# MS SQL Server Update in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Im trying to update a table in `C#`

```
int record_id = 123;    

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlServer)) {

    SqlCommand mySqlCommand;

    string sql = "UPDATE my_table SET foo = @foo WHERE id = @id;";

    connection.Open();

    mySqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = sql;

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@foo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@foo"].Value = "bar";

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = record_id;

    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

When executed, I get a 500 server error with the following message:

> ----- The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.   Most likely causes:
>
> IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during
>   the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on
>   which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker
>   process when this error occurred.
>
> IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or
>   application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set
>   incorrectly.
>
> IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or
>   application.   The authenticated user does not have permission to use
>   this DLL.
>
> The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
>
> ### Feature is not installed.

Im not really a C#/.NET developer and not certain about the syntax here. I do know that the line `mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` causes the error.

There are also other SQL requests on the page (that I did not write) and they execute without issues. Unfortunately, none of them are `update` requests that I can use as an example.

Comment: 1. Change your web.config so that it shows errors. 2. Can you use a debugger? 3. Your `connection.Close()` line is superflouous because you have a `using` block. 4. You can use `cmd.Parameters.Add( ... ).Value = "bar" to set a value when you create a `SqlParameter`.

Comment: the record_id is an int but the parameter is a varchar, i would change that but it will most likely not solve your problem. Enabling debug, in the web.config will give you more information.

Comment: I normally dont work with C#/.NET and not familiar with the debugger. I have Visual Studio Code but by the time I get my dev environment set up to mirror production, it would barely be worth it. I would prefer to steer clear of web.config since Im working on a live environment and its pretty easy to crash the server

Comment: A long shot but you could try `int rowsAffected = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`. `rowsAffected` won't be used but it might be expecting it because a value is returned (-1).